# Extends 2 classes - fill the blanks - last exam rehearse

Tags: java

I am preparing to Java exam on my finals. I have encountered a question in which i need to fill blank spaces.

The relevant piece of code where i need to fill blank spaces

```
____ ____ C {}
____ B extends ____ , C {}
```

The question is : Can i insert all those blanks to have my program compiled?

I know that i cannot make class which extends from 2 classes. But maybe there is some kind of keyword which will make this compile.

Personally, I think that there should be "implements" keyword before C and then it would look like this. Maybe it's a typo made by guy from previous academic year.

```
public interface C {}
class B extends Object implements C {} //good enough
```

Also i could fill last blank with large snippet where i declare new class but i don't think it's case.

Still. Can i fill only blanks to compile code in first snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both C and B should be interfaces.
Example below (I used `Closeable` interface in one of the blanks, but you can use any known from JDK)

```
public interface C {}
interface B extends Closeable, C {}
```

When interfaces inherit one another, they use the `extends` keyword instead of `implements` (which is used when class is inheriting from interface).

Comment: I did not know that extends can also be used for interfaces. Great job, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here we go - A interface can extend multiple interface.

```
public interface C {}
interface B extends Runnable, C {}
```